# How to trigger an event when thread completes its work

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, threadpool

Use case: Created thread pool in C++ and assigned the work to all the threads. I want to trigger an event when thread from threadpool completes its work.

But I don't know how to trigger an event when thread from thread pool completes its work.

Example:

```
void ThreadPoolImpl::InitThreadPool(){
pool = CreateThreadpool(NULL);
if (pool == NULL)
{
    //Log("Could not create a thread pool!");
    return;
}
InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment(&environment);
cleanupGroup = CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup();
if (cleanupGroup == NULL)
{
    //Log("Could not create a thread pool cleanup group!");
}
SetThreadpoolCallbackPool(&environment, pool);
SetThreadpoolCallbackCleanupGroup(&environment, cleanupGroup, NULL);}


void ThreadPoolImpl::RunThreads(int const iThreadCount)
```

{

```
dwThreadCount = iThreadCount;
if (dwThreadCount == 0)
{
    dwThreadCount = DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT;
}
SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum(pool, dwThreadCount);
SetThreadpoolThreadMinimum(pool, MIN_THREAD_COUNT);


work = CreateThreadpoolWork(workcallback,NULL,&environment);

if (NULL == work) {
    _tprintf(_T("CreateThreadpoolWork failed. LastError: %u\n"),
        GetLastError());
}

SubmitThreadpoolWork(work);//Want to trigger an event for each thread in thread pool
```

}

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prevent this question from being closed by creating a good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [condition_variable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/) for each thread.